# What happened to Cloud Run for GKE?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Several resources on the web point to the existence of Cloud Run for GKE. For example, this Google [codelabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-run-gke/), this YouTube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RVdhyprptTQ) from Google and this LinkedIn training [video](https://www.linkedin.com/learning/google-cloud-platform-essential-training-3/google-cloud-run-on-gke).

However the Cloud Run for GKE functionality seems to have disappeared when you try to create a new Kubernetes cluster, using the Google Cloud web console. The checkboxes to enable Istio and Cloud Run for GKE underneath "Additional features" are not available anymore. (see [3:40](https://www.linkedin.com/learning/google-cloud-platform-essential-training-3/google-cloud-run-on-gke) on this LinkedIn video tutorial)

The official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/gke/setup) about Cloud run for GKE also seems to have disappeared or changed and replaced with documentation about Cloud Run on Anthos.

So, in short, what happened to Cloud Run for GKE?

Comment: Google Cloud Run is/will be removed from GKE and will be part of the Google Anthos product offering which includes GKE. Google Anthos is an entire platform layer on top of Kubernetes. Cloud Run for Anthos still runs on GKE, but will only be available as part of Anthos product/licensing.

Answer (score 6):

You first need to create a GKE cluster and then when creating cloud run choose `CloudRun for Anthos` so, it's not really gone anywhere.

[image: Here it is!]

If it was greyed out, that was probably because you had to tick "enabled stackdriver..."

Comment: Thanks I've tried it, it does provide you with another "deployment platform" when you try to create a new Cloud Run service. However I thought Anthos was only a solution if you want to create a hybrid cloud environment, the name change is confusing. So basically "Cloud run for GKE" now seems to be called "Cloud run for Anthos".

Comment: You could say that. But do recall it was (and is) termed "beta" and so that means its not the final version. Essentially, it is the same thing for us, the underlying logic must have changed and hence the name "Anthos".

Answer (score 4):

I think it is just a change of words and not functionality.

If you check [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/gke/setup) out you'll see it specifically says:

> This guide shows how to set up a new Google Kubernetes Engine cluster with Cloud Run for Anthos on Google Cloud enabled.

It starts off with creating a GKE cluster which has two ways:

1. Using GCP console
2. Using `gcloud` command-line tool

I prefer `gcloud` command-line tool using which you need the following command to create a cluster:

```
gcloud beta container clusters create CLUSTER_NAME \
--addons=HorizontalPodAutoscaling,HttpLoadBalancing,Istio,CloudRun \
--machine-type=n1-standard-4 \
--cluster-version=GKE_VERSION
--enable-stackdriver-kubernetes \
--scopes cloud-platform
```

If you look closely at the add-ons, you will see it has `Istio` and `CloudRun`. The most important flag here is `--enable-stackdriver-kubernetes`, you would have to enable Stackdriver for Kubernetes in order to move forward.

Looking at your question, I believe you are using GCP Console. The same should be done via console. If you choose the appropriate version of GKE, it will give you options to enable **Istio** ad well as **Cloud Run**.

Initially, the checkbox to `Enable Cloud Run for Anthos (beta)` will be grayed out if `Enable legacy Stackdriver Logging service` and `Enable legacy Stackdriver Monitoring service` is enabled `Enable Stackdriver Kubernetes Engine Monitoring` disabled.

So firstly select `Enable Stackdriver Kubernetes Engine Monitoring` and now after selecting `Enable Istio (beta)`, you should see the checkbox for `Enable Cloud Run for Anthos (beta)` working.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/gke/cluster-versions) is the list of available GKE versions for Cloud Run.

If you follow the guide carefully, you will simply be able to create a GKE cluster and deploy a Hello World application on Cloud Run for ***Anthos*** (GKE).

I hope this helps!!

Answer (score 3):

Cloud Run for GKE did not disappear but it was simply renamed to "Cloud Run for Anthos".

Initially I thought Anthos was a technology for multicloud environments, but it seems to be more of a "brand name".

> The answer is that Anthos is not really a technology, but more of a
>   brand, a wrapper around Google's cloud crown jewels, Kubernetes (K8s).

This is quoted from this post on [TheRegister](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2019/09/18/google_anthos_new_features_announced/).

Comment: Google Anthos is an entire platform layer on top of Kubernetes. It not simply a rebranding. GKE is part of Anthos. Anthos is not part of GKE.